# Link my Pewdiepie's Tuber Simulator account onto my new phone?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

I feel like an idiot asking this question, because many people asked it before, but their solutions aren't helping me.

I got a new phone today, and I want to play my old Pewdiepie's Tuber Simulator account on my new phone. I linked it onto my Game Centre account on my old phone (many times), like people told me to do. I went to download the game on my new phone through icloud and it only gives me the option to start a new game... so I decide to start a new game and go into the friends section to see if i can link my old account through the Game Centre.

Only it doesn't. It just says link my NEW account to my Game Centre, and it gets rid of my old account. So I go back onto my old phone and link that again, and return the to Tuber app on my new phone, but nothing's changed, it's still that new account that I had to make.

I'm very confused and frustrated, especially since I spent hours on that game, and spent forever to get to level 23, set up a bunch of rooms, etc, and my old phone is going to be donated soon.

Does anyone have any idea whats wrong, or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. For anyone who wants to know, go onto your old device, go onto the app, go to the little gear at the top while you're in play mode (its next to the top tuber verified users list). These are the options. Click on options underneath credits. Click "link account", it will ask you what device it is, click on the option that is right for you, and then click "old device". It will say to log onto your Game Center account, or the equivalent to what ever phone you're using. Log on.

Get your new phone, go on the app, and repeat the process but this time say that this is your new device. It might ask you to log into your Game Center account if you haven't already. It should automatically go to your saved account from your old device.